# Facebook sharer and links with GET parameters

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm using Facebook sharer in my app for links with GET parameters. Some parameters can be empty, for example:

```
mywebsite.com/?search=&field=5&field6=&field1=qwe
```

I'm encoding my url with urllib:

```
urllib.quote(url, safe='')
```

Then passing this encoded url to facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=ENCODEDURL.
And then link in result post is going to be like that:

```
mywebsite.com/?search&field=5&field6&field1=qwe
```

In all the other socials such as Twitter, Vk everything is ok, but facebook doesn't want to decode my url properly. What did I miss?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't want to decode?

Comment: Facebook sharer receives encoded URL and when the shared post with link created, it should be decoded URL